# Non blocking connect in Java

Tags: java, tcp, client, connect, nonblocking

What is the best way to accomplish a non blocking TCP connect in Java? I want to be able to use the socket with ordinary streams (occasionally SSL). I also have to target Android 2.1, so I can't afford the latest and the greatest.

Comment: Use a blocking TCP connection, but place the code that manages it on a separate thread?

Comment: I am doing this, but the connect may block quite a while, depending on the networking conditions. Especially when e phone keeps switching between gsm and umts for instance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`SocketChannel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html) and [`configureBlocking(false)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/spi/AbstractSelectableChannel.html#configureBlocking%28boolean%29). If you have more than one non-blocking I/O channel and you intend to use them all from a single thread you will probably find [`Selector`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Selector.html) very useful, too.

Note that it is generally easier and less error-prone to use blocking sockets and use multiple threads to make sure your app can continue doing useful work while it is blocked waiting for I/O to complete.

Comment: +1: Totally agree. Blocking mode is the default, and you don't need to call configureBlocking to use it. NIO Was introduced in Java 1.4 in 2002 and pre-dates Android by a few years. ;)

Comment: I have thought about using NIO, but it doesn't really work well with SSL, does it?

Comment: There indeed seem to be issues with passing SSLSocketChannel to Selector. If you use Selector see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/867751/ssl-and-socketchannel). Unfortunately a link in the first answer seems broken.